# Changing themes and icons with Unity or Ubuntu Tweak, but getting same menu bar "defaults"

Tags: unity, themes, icons, 15.10, menu-bar

On Ubuntu 15.10, using Unity or Ubuntu tweak, I can change my Theme and Icons.  But for some Icon sets, the menu bar icons seem to be the same.  For example, this is what the menu icons for "Breeze-dark" looks like:

[image: Breeze Dark]

And this is what the menu icons for "locolor" look like:

[image]

The other (non-menu bar) icons *do* change throughout the rest of the gui (see,e.g., the directory icons), but the menu icons are essentially identical.

I get the sense the "Breeze-dark" is falling back on a *default icon set* for the menu items, but I can't figure out where it is or, more importantly, how to change it.

At the end of the day, I'd like to keep the "Breeze-dark" icon set for the general os, but swap out the menu bar icons for something a bit more consistent, like these from the Faba icon set menu bar:

[image]

Or just generally mix and match.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am experimenting myself with icon themes.
You can try this:

Edit the index.theme file that is in te icon theme folder. It should be under ~/.icons/breeze-dark or /usr/share/icons/breeze-dark
and change the line that says

```
Inherits=hicolor
```

adding the name of a theme (in the first place) that you have intalled in the system and that has the top panel menus that you like. In my case:

```
Inherits=clear,hicolor
```

Comment: Brilliant!  Thank you!  I edited `Inherits=` to include a list of my favorite icon sets, starting with the best first.  I noticed that sometimes an icon set doesn't include a particular icon, so the secondary and tertiary sets listed apparently fill those gaps.

Comment: You're welcome. And, yes, I forgot to add that you can add a list of themes to inherit missing icons ;)